# How to check if a button was clicked in MS word?

Tags: c#, ms-word, autohotkey

I am currently trying to use a script (`Autohotkey`) to do some MS word manipulations, which will send key strokes and mouse clicks to MS word, but sometimes the click may fail (due to wrong XY coordinates etc).

To log those error clicks (on unclickable areas), I would like to be awared every time a button on MS word is clicked with the help of C# (better if it can tell me which button it is, if not just knowing "some button was clicked" is also okay).

I wonder if there's any good approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Instead for detecting certain locations in word or other programs, use ControlSend
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm
with 
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlGet.htm

This way you can send input directly to the specified control in a window.

Comment: Thank you dexter4712345, I guess you also mean ControlClick, this does not work for MS word since Window Spy cannot detect the text of most of the buttons and some of them are an image without text. And to change the way doing clicking would influence a large number of scripts and we'll have to redo all previous work and testings. I would say this is my last choice.